# Is it possible to "lock" a JSON document without a server - only JSON and client?

Tags: javascript, json, security, locking, client

I'm working on a project where I'm using a cross-storage JavaScript library ([JIO](http://www.j-io.org/)), which allows to store/share/sync JSON documents across different storages (S3, Dav, etc).

Security aside, I'm wondering whether there is any way to prevent editing of a collaboratively shared document at a certain "stage". For example, if adocument is "published", it should no longer be possible to be edited, even by users who have a permission to edit.

I can define a status and store this in the `document meta`, so I would return something like this to the client:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "created": "2013/12/01:11:10:59",
  "state": "published"
  ...
}
```

Of course I can prevent editing if `state !== "published"` in my method doing the edit and save, but when I can essentially trigger any method I want in Firebug, I don't see who I could prevent tampering documents.

**Question:**
Is there any way to **"lock"** a JSON document to prevent if from being edited **without** using a server?

Comment: There's nothing inherent that you can rely on.  It's just a structured text document.  If you have additional access control requirements you need to implement that on top of JSON as an additional thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as you described it reminds me how the Bitcoin protocol works. In your case the blockchain is a list of published documents and "double-spending" is publishing document twice.

In brief, if someone publishes the document, it is recorded and shared between other clients and another client can publish the next document by calculating RSA hash of the previous document and the new document. In other words, records of published documents form a chain and this chain is distributed between all clients. In this case if the document is published once no other client can republish it because it will be just ignored by other clients (as all of them knows that it was already published).

So, I think that it is possible to create an algorithm that allows to "publish" shared documents without trusted server but it is quite complicated.

Comment: Cool. Good idea. Agree it's  complicated ... :-)